# Having separate themes - if the same host address has www. and a version with no www.

Tags: asp.net

I have a set of themes for my website, which are to be used with different requests from different urls. So if the url = www.xyz.com I load a different theme, as opposed to www.abc.com.

However, I have tried having a theme called www.abc.com and a theme called abc.com, and in my webform codebehind I have a `preinit page` event which says if `url.contains(abc.com)`, then load theme abc.com, if `url.contains(www.abc.com)`, then load theme www.abc.com (valid theme).

Starting from the beginning again, what is the best way to have and call a theme depending on whether the url has www. or not, but the same host. So how can I have separate themes for abc.com and www.abc.com, and then load the latter when the url is www.abc.com and the former when the url, is obviously, abc.com?

Comment: FYI - THis is a BAD idea from an SEO perspective as you will be knocked for duplicate content most likely.

Comment: @Mitchel - is that because of the different "theming".. certainly since almost every domain can be reached with or without the leading `www.`, that would mean that every site would suffer?

Comment: if the theme is merely styling, it shouldn't matter; personally I would hate to use a site that did what @GSS is asking, because changing the layout/colors/whathaveyou just because I prefer without `www.` and someone else uses `www.` would be very annoying

Comment: SEO recommendations are that you should choose a domain style and stick to it, and redirect requests to the other format to the preferred one. Google Webmaster Tools have a facility to help with this - you can ask it to show all pages to your site as either www.example.com, example.com or "however they were indexed". With examples like this, the duplicate content is just that you'll be fighting with yourself for ranking - if you only respond on example.com, all links to your site count for that domain, whereas if you respond on both, your rank will be split between them effectively halving it.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you're after here, but if you are testing the url in that order, and using an else, then it looks like the first case will always be true, so test for the more specific case (www) first.

Would also suggest that you look at testing for url.StartsWith, and include the protocol variations that you might expect, as you never know if those strings might show up somewhere else in the url in a year or two, and your theme switcher might stop working.

You could then just swap around master pages to change your theme, or if you are using the App_Theme thing, do some switching on that. Always found the aspnet theme thing to be a little bit clunky myself.